# Could someone help me to explain this line of code

Tags: python, list

Im new to python, and I saw this line of code online. Im not quite fully understand it. I hope you can help me to explain this.

```
[item for list in total_list for item in list]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

The equivalent code would be:

```
l = []
for list in total_list:
    for item in list:
        l.append(item)
```

This specific comprehension has two for loops, here's an example with one:

```
>>> [i*i for i in range(5)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

On the left you put the value you want to "append" to the list, and to the right of that goes the for loop (or multiple for loops in order of left to right). List (and dictionary) comprehensions are a feature of python that provide a more elegant and efficient way to construct dicts/lists. They're super powerful and you should use them whenever you can (it's much more pythonic than using for loops and appending).

You can also choose to "append" to the list only if a given condition is True. For example, let's say we only want to "append" if the number is even:

```
>>> [i for i in range(6) if i % 2 == 0]
[0, 2, 4]
```

The equivalent code in this case is:

```
l = []
for i in range(6):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        l.append(i)
```